# JUnit in Codename One

Tags: testing, junit, codenameone

I am writing a cross platform application in Codename One. I have to do this in testing first mode.

Is it possible to include JUnit tests in a Codename One project? And if so, how can I do it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Codename One doesn't support `JUnit` since it requires introspection/reflection both of which aren't practical on mobile devices which either obfuscate or translate the code to C (for the iOS port).

You can use `JUnit` to test "business logic" in a separate project but that's not for everything. Codename One has its own testing framework and test recorder see http://www.codenameone.com/blog/test-it.html

FYI the latest version of the plugin seems to have a regression here which we are trying to address: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1443

Comment: Are there any examples of unit testing with Codename One? How can an application be developed with TDD? The blog post that you linked to shows integration testing via the UI.

Comment: Is there any test runner integration with the IDE? Can I write a test and run it from NetBeans and see if the test passes or fails? Is there support for fixtures or spies or mocks?

Comment: The integration is very basic, you can execute the tests from the IDE using the right click menu or standard test bindings (depends on the IDE). Mocks should be easy but we don't have them. Personally I'd rather have device farm integration than any of the above but we are driven by demand and we don't have enough user demand around this.